# I want to pass Payload /Request body to apisauce

Tags: reactjs, axios, apisauce

Hi I am using applesauce for API calls. I want to add the request body to the request.I added the body as the last code, but it is not working. I create authSauace from apisauce as follows.

```
import { create } from "apisauce";
import { AUTHORIZATION } from "../constants/commonStrings";
export const authSauce = create({  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_BASE, });
export const setHeadersForAllInstances = (token) => {   authSauce.setHeader(AUTHORIZATION, `Bearer ${token}`);};
```

And then I want to add payload as below

```
authSauce
  .get(`/api/query`, null, {
      payload: {}
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      }
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.data) {
      console.log(response.data);
    }
  })
```

Comment: "I cannot add it" is not a problem description. Is the 2nd block of code what you tried? What happens when you run it? Why is that wrong/insufficient?

Comment: this code is not passing the body